# how to extract text from double lines pdf

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I have some pdf files, which have double columns per page. I want to extract text from those files by program. The content of pdf file is Chinese. I tried to use pdfminer3k library of python3 and ghostscript, whose result are all not very good.

At last, I use the github open source project named `textract`, and the link is [deanmalmgren/textract](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract).

But `textract` can not detect that the every page that contains two columns. I use the following command:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("/home/name/Downloads/textract-master/test.pdf")
print text
```

And pdf file link is https://pan.baidu.com/s/1nvLQnLf
The output result shows that the extract program regards the two columns as one column. I want to extract the double columns pdf files. How to solve?

This is the output result by extract program.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJO5D.png
This is the output result by extract program.